# How to move property value from Properties file to payload object using spring integration elements

Tags: spring, spring-integration

```
Sample.properties
=================
http.header.amisys.accept.value=arun/vnd.dsths.services-v1+xml

1)Above XSL automatically loaded when my server starts.
2)I have tried <int:enricher>  element but it is not helped me.
```

Sample Code : Below is bit of code I have tried, Can any one suggest me on this.

```
    <int:channel id="PQLegacySecurity-InputChannel" />
    <int:chain input-channel="PQLegacySecurity-InputChannel" >
        <!-- Split the Search Request Params from Xml  -->
        <int-xml:xpath-splitter>
        <int-xml:xpath-expression expression="//LegacySecurity"  namespace map="xmlMessageNamespace" />
        </int-xml:xpath-splitter>           
        <int:enricher  >               
          <int:payload name="testPayload" expression="${http.header.amisys.accept.value}"/>                  
        </int:enricher>         
    </int:chain>        

Actual Payload Object:Below is the xml which does not contain  testPayload property.

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><LegacySecurity>
                  <businessArea>%%%%%%</businessArea>
                  <LegacySystem>%%%%%</LegacySystem>
                  <LegacyUserID>%%%%%</LegacyUserID>
                  <LegacyPassword>%%%%%</LegacyPassword>
                  <OtherLogin/>
                  <OtherPassword/>
                  <AddSecurLogin/>
                  <AddSecurPassword/>
                  </LegacySecurity>
```

Expected Payload Object: Below Object contains new element testPayload node which I should able to        add

```
                 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><LegacySecurity>
                  <businessArea>%%%%%%</businessArea>
                  <LegacySystem>%%%%%</LegacySystem>
                  <LegacyUserID>%%%%%</LegacyUserID>
                  <LegacyPassword>%%%%%</LegacyPassword>
                  <OtherLogin/>
                  <OtherPassword/>
                  **<testPayload>arun/vnd.dsths.services-v1+xml</testPayload>**
                  <AddSecurLogin/>
                  <AddSecurPassword/>
                  </LegacySecurity>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an xslt transformer. Something like the below, though you will need to figure out correct use of the transformer from the spring docs.

Notice you can pass a parameter through to the XSLT

```
<int-xml:xslt-transformer result-transformer="toDocumentTransformer" result-type="StringResult" xsl-resource="/xslt/addTestPayload.xslt">
     <int-xml:xslt-param name="testPayload" value="${http.header.amisys.accept.value}"/>
</int-xml:xslt-transformer>
```

In the XSLT file, use this to pick up the parameter:

```
<xsl:param name="testPayload" />
```

If you have other changes you need to make to the message you can use the same xslt.

Comment: <int-xml:xslt-transformer result-transformer="resultToString" result-type="StringResult" xsl-resource="${stylesheet.amisys.soaXml.PQLegacySecurityTest}">
        <int-xml:xslt-param name="testPayload" value="${http.header.amisys.accept.value}"/>
        </int-xml:xslt-transformer>

Comment: I have tried above ,but i am getting error like Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'resultToString' is defined

Comment: I have tried another by removing result-transformer="resultToString" ,but it giving error like Compiler warnings:
  line 6: Illegal attribute 'value'., Can  you please help me on this

Comment: The toDocumentTransformer is a reference to a Spring managed bean. So you need to define this bean in the xml.  So if you want to use the resultToString transformer you need to define this bean: `<bean id="resultToString" class="org.springframework.integration.xml.transformer.ResultToStringTransformer" />`